# How to restrict a text field to certain language using JS?

Tags: javascript, text, non-english

I'm building Q&A application and I want to restrict users to use only arabic as language in asking their questions or answering them, I believe JS is able to detect what keyboard is being used and also I want to prevent users from pasting code in other language than arabic too
Thanks

Comment: Can this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517440/allow-only-arabic-letters-in-textbox-using-javascript

Comment: Might code in Arabic nevertheless contain English words or at least roman characters, depending on the language?  Like `متغير = $(header).val("نص")`?  You may be better off making a warning appear if no Arabic is used in a post.

Comment: I wondered this too, what do you do with foreign proper nouns, e.g. "Microsoft" or "Google"?

Comment: yes I'm sure only arabic would be used, for english names users can still type them in arabic Microsoft would be ميكروسوفت...

Comment: Hi Edward the link you gave me they use ASP!